# 形式として問題ないのに JSON.parse で エラーになってしまう

Tags: javascript, json

electron(v22)+Vue(v3)を使って、JSONで処理しようとしています。

アップロードしたファイルをテキストファイルをJSONにパースしようとするとエラーが発生します。
もしかしたら改行コードやスペースが原因かと思い、最小構成のJSONを作ってみました。
しかし、それでもエラーが発生します。

```
const text = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
const json = JSON.parse(text);
```

テストしたテキストファイルは次のようなものです。改行コードもありません

```
{"test":"text"}
```

発生するエラーは次のとおりです。

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '', "{"test":"text"}" is not valid JSON
```

toStringを付けてみましたが同じでした。

```
JSON.parse(text.toString())
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '', "{"test":"text"}" is not valid JSON
```

直接、テキスト文を書き込むと問題ありません

```
JSON.parse('{"test":"test"}')
> Object {test: "test"}
```

エラーが発生してしまう原因がわかりません。
何が原因と考えられるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

【追記】
デバッグコンソールでいろいろとテストをしてみました。

1. JSON.parse(text) で エラー
2. text の中は '{"test":"text"}'
3. '{"test":"text"}'を手打ちでJSON.parse だと正常
4. text と 手打ち '{"test":"text"}' を比較すると false

見た目は一緒だけど、中身が違うと認識されているようです。
文字コードはUTF-8、そもそも記号とアルファベットだけなので文字コードも影響がないはずでは？

typeof(text) を実行してみると string が返ってきました。

うーーん、本当何が原因なんでしょう

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Unicode文字にはゼロ幅の文字もあります。見た目では判断できないので 1文字ずつ取り出し文字コード表示するとかしたほうがよいかも

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、最初の１文字目が U+FEFF でした。「BOM付きUTF-8」というものでした。この１文字を削除してみると問題なくJSON化できました。見えないだけに全く気づくことが出来ませんでした

Answer (score 4, accepted):

対象ファイルが「BOM付きUTF-8」でした。
先頭の１文字に U+FEFF がついており、そのためにJSON.parseがエラーになる原因でした。
"幅ゼロの文字" のため、テキストベースでは気づけませんでした。

下記のコードで削除することで問題なくJSON化出来ました。

```
let text = await fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
if (text.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
    text = text.substring(1);
}
const json = JSON.parse(text);
```

（コメントでご指摘頂いた内容です。解決しましたので回答として投稿いたします）